# Why doesn't this iAd properly disappear?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iad

```
// iAd Advertising
#pragma mark iAd Delegate Methods

- (void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

} // if there is an internet connection, load the iAd with a 1 second fade in effect

- (void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0]; 
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

When `setAlpha` is `0`, shouldn't it disappear as opposed to displaying a white line across the screen as a replacement for the ad that isn't there?

I want the banner to completely disappear, but it shows a white banner instead. I've used this type of animating before and had no problem with it making things completely disappear. Is it because it is an iAd banner?

Comment: i had this same problem so I just created an adbanner property and would use the hidden function to hide it

Comment: could you provide an example of the code? @Rookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your alpha to 0 in your storyboard on the iAd. Then it will work with the code you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

In your header file..

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet ADBannerView *adBanner;
```

In your implementation file..

```
- (void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    adBanner.hidden = 0;

}

- (void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    adBanner.hidden = 1;
}
```

Comment: Sam pointed out my error on my now-deleted incorrect answer. Glad you got something that worked. :)